# NoData strip appears after MODIS data downloaded from GEE

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, modis, nodata

In Google Earth Engine, I used the following code to generate a MODIS NDVI `ImageCollection`.

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MYD09GA_006_NDVI")
  .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2023-01-01')
  .select(["NDVI"]);
var chinaBoundary = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(70, 0, 136, 56);
// var chinaBoundary = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(97, 26, 109, 35);
var selectedDays = ee.List.sequence(200, 210, 3);

var filterAndClip = function(day) {
  var filtered = ndvi.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(day, day, 'day_of_year'))
    .map(function(image) {
      // return image.clip(chinaBoundary).reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 500);
      return image.clip(chinaBoundary);
    });
  return filtered;
};

var ndvi_china = ee.ImageCollection([]);

for (var i = 0; i < selectedDays.length().getInfo(); i++) {
  var day = selectedDays.get(i);
  var filtered = filterAndClip(day);
  ndvi_china = ndvi_china.merge(filtered);
}

Map.addLayer(ndvi_china, {}, 'NDVI_Now');
Map.centerObject(ndvi_china, 5);

var options = {
  name: '{system_date}',
  dateFormat: 'yyyyDDD',
  scale: 500,
  maxPixels: 10000000000000,
  region: chinaBoundary
};
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(ndvi_china, "ndvi_8_days", options)
```

In GEE, whether using sinusoidal projection (SR-ORG:6974) or WGS_84 (EPSG:4326), there is no problem looking from GEE's map.
[image]

However, after downloading this data to the local through Drive, a black `NoData` value area appears as shown in the figure below.
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is that when you visualize the ImageCollection in GEE, the four images contained in your Image Collection are shown. Thus, the pixels with No Data values seem to be filled by the pixels in other images. This might be clearer if you visualize one image at a time. For example:

```
var dateStart = ee.Date.fromYMD(2022,1,1).advance(208, 'day');
var dateEnd = dateStart.advance(2,'day');
Map.addLayer(ndvi_china.filterDate(dateStart,dateEnd).first(), {}, 'NDVI_filter');
```

[image]

Therefore, if you wish to obtain a composite similar to what GEE is showing, you can build a composite from the four images contained in your image collection and export that single image. In this example, I used a median reducer:

```
var resul = ndvi_china.median()
Map.addLayer(resul, {}, 'NDVI_Now');
```

[image: composite]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solved my recent doubts. I'm very sorry, I'm not very familiar with GEE, so this error occurred. The `merge` function was used earlier, but I forgot about it when it came to the `Map` function below. So yesterday, I thought this was caused by the inconsistency between the default projection of GEE and the projection during export. Got it, thank you very much for your time and answer. I wish you all the best!